Get alibaba search results filtered by Place of Origin
do you know if there is a way to get search results on Alibaba filtering by region (place of origin) ? For example, in the below image Place of Origin is "Jiangsu"... any idea or script ?

I've been looking for a solution for it, but I did not find anything yet. Thank you!!
